# Updating a vector in cuda kernel only for some threads

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I'm new with CUDA, and now I'm trying to do some simple so operations. In this case I have a vector of vectors `Vertex** a`, that is a list of nodes, and I want to call the kernel so that each thread takes only one node, and in the kernel does a check. If this check is verified, than the thread has to add the element in the vector `a`.
The first problem is initializing the `d_a[0]` element with cudaMalloc, because as i saw on other questions, I cannot do:

```
cudaMalloc(&d_a[0], ((numNodes/2)+1) * sizeof(Vertex));
```

So I did as you can see below in the code, but I'm not sure this is ok...

This is what I have done in the main:

```
    Vertex** d_a;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, 1 * sizeof(Vertex*));
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, maxBis, 1 * sizeof(Vertex*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int* d_allLen;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_allLen, 1 * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemset(d_allLen, 0, 1 * sizeof(int));

    int blockSize = min(128, numNodes); 
    int blockCount = (numNodes + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;

    preprocess_initial_partition_CUDA<<<blockCount, blockSize>>>(d_initial_partition, numNodes, d_nonLeaves, d_a, d_allLen, index);
```

and this is my simple kernel:

```
__global__ void preprocess_initial_partition_CUDA(Vertex* d_initial_partition, int numNodes, Vertex* d_nonLeaves, Vertex** d_a, int* d_allLen, int index) {
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int globalThreadId = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + tid;

    if (globalThreadId < numNodes) {  
        if (d_initial_partition[globalThreadId].deg == 0) {
            atomicAdd(d_allLen, 1);  
            d_a[index][d_allLen[index]-1] = d_initial_partition[globalThreadId];
        } else {
            d_nonLeaves[globalThreadId] = d_initial_partition[globalThreadId];
        }
    }
}
```

in this kernel i take the Id of each thread, and so, it the relative node has 0 degree, add it to the d_a vector. I do an `atomicAdd` on d_allLen so that I have the total amount of nodes that have 0 deg, and it is ok, the problem is just for the line
`d_a[index][d_allLen[index]-1] = d_initial_partition[globalThreadId];` that makes, at the end of the kernel, the value of `d_allLen` wrong. How can i populate correctly the `d_a` vector?

Comment: Why do you want a `Vertex**`? Can't you allocate a flatten array of `Vertex` which should be more efficient? A `Vertex*` array is only useful if you want to dynamically reallocate some parts or not allocate a big block.

Comment: `d_a[index][d_allLen[index]-1]` after an `atomicAdd` is scary and likely bogus. It increase the value at `d_allLen[0]` while `d_allLen[index]` is a non-atomic read (which might cause a race condition, especially if `index` is 0). And `d_allLen[index]-1` is AFAIK undefined behaviour (UB) if the value `d_allLen[index]` is 0 (while `d_allLen` is initialized with zeros). Note that when you do an atomic operation in parallel, the value of the atomic variable after that is often unpredictable. This is why `atomicAdd` has a return value.

Comment: I want a Vertex** because this one should be only the first operation on the initial group of vertex, so I would do this kernel just to found that vertexes than had deg=0 and place them in the first position of d_a and I would do that in parallel.  After this I want to do more and populate the other positions... So I don't understand how to populate it and keep the count of the number of elements.

Comment: One problem with `**` is [coalesced global access](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory) which is very important for performance in bandwidth-limited algorithms in GPU computing. `**` is also a problematic pattern in CPU computing (see pointer chasing) which is why HPC code for sparse linear algebra uses flattened formats like [CSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)).